# Add SKSpriteNode to UITabeViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift, uikit, sprite-kit

I am creating a collecting game using Swift and SpriteKit.  I have decided to leverage the UITableView from UIKit since it is a pretty convenient prepackaged way to display a large collection.  However, many of the items that get collected in the game are rendered dynamically as an SKSpriteNode.  What is the best way to add an SKSpriteNode to a UITableViewCell?  I know there are ways to render an SKNode as a SKTexture, but then, how does one render a UIImage from that Texture?

This code does not work:

```
    let spriteView = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "bug.png") )
    cell?.imageView.addSubview(spriteView)
    return cell
```

Comment: can't be done ... nodes are not views. You need to create and add UIImage(View) instances

Comment: @LearnCocos2D What about the idea of creating a custom UITableViewCell class which includes an SKNode as one of it's elements, instead of a UIImage?

Comment: can't be done ... nodes are not views. Consider the implications of that fact. A node is drawn by a SKView and its currently active scene. And no, you can't create multiple SKView either, not on iOS and not in a way where each view renders its contents consistenly and frequently (usually only one skview is updated concistently, the others may not draw at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LearnCocos2D deserves the credit for this one. He was completely correct that there is no way to add UI-anything to spritekit nodes, or to add nodes of any sort to UIKit table views. Inconvenient, but true. If LearnCocos2D posts an answer I'll happily accept it as the correct one, in the meantime, I am posting this one for the purposes of closure.